# How to get sub path from the given file path

Tags: java

I want to get path after given token "html" which is a fix token and file path is below

```
String token = "html"
Path path = D:\data\test\html\css\Core.css
Expected Output : css\Core.css
```

below is input folder for the program. and defined as the constant in the code.

```
public static final String INPUT_DIR = "D:\data\test\html"
```

which will contains input html, css, js files. and want to copy these files to different location E:\data\test\html\ here so just need to extract sub path after html from the input file path to append it to the output path.

lets say input file are

```
D:\data\test\html\css\Core.css
D:\data\test\html\css\Core.html
D:\data\test\html\css\Core.js
```

so want to extract css\Core.css, css\Core.html, css\Core.js to append it to the destination path E:\data\test\html\ to copy it.

Tried below
String [] array = path.tostring().split("html");
String subpath = array[1];

```
Output : \css\Core.css
```

which is not expected output expected output is css\Core.css
Also above code is not working for below path

```
Path path = D:\data\test\html\bla\bla\html\css\Core.css;
String [] array = path.toString().split("html");
String subpath = array[1];
```

In this case I am getting something like \bla\bla\ which is not
expected.

Comment: String.split() should do.

Comment: but i dont want to iterate over the array to get it. is there no function to get it .

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the path in the form of a string another solution would be to use this code:

```
String path = "D:\\data\\test\\html\\css\\Core.css";
String keyword = "\\html";

System.out.println(path.substring(path.lastIndexOf(keyword) + keyword.length()).trim());
```

You can replace the path with file.getAbsolutePath() as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

```java
    import java.io.File;
    
    public class Main {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a File object for the directory that you want to start from
        File directory = new File("/path/to/starting/directory");
    
        // Get a list of all files and directories in the directory
        File[] files = directory.listFiles();
    
        // Iterate through the list of files and directories
        for (File file : files) {
          // Check if the file is a directory
          if (file.isDirectory()) {
            // If it's a directory, recursively search for the file
            findFile(file, "target-file.txt");
          } else {
            // If it's a file, check if it's the target file
            if (file.getName().equals("target-file.txt")) {
              // If it's the target file, print the file path
              System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
            }
          }
        }
      }
    
      public static void findFile(File directory, String targetFileName) {
        // Get a list of all files and directories in the directory
        File[] files = directory.listFiles();
    
        // Iterate through the list of files and directories
        for (File file : files) {
          // Check if the file is a directory
          if (file.isDirectory()) {
            // If it's a directory, recursively search for the file
            findFile(file, targetFileName);
          } else {
            // If it's a file, check if it's the target file
            if (file.getName().equals(targetFileName)) {
              // If it's the target file, print the file path
              System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

This code uses a recursive function to search through all subdirectories of the starting directory and print the file path of the target file (in this case, "target-file.txt") if it is found.

You can modify this code to suit your specific needs, such as changing the starting directory or target file name. You can also modify the code to perform different actions on the target file, such as reading its contents or copying it to another location.

Answer (score 0):

Your question lacks details.

- Is the "path" a [Path](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html) or a [String](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html)?
- How do you determine which part of the "path" you want?
- Do you know the entire structure of the "path" or do you just have the delimiting part, for example the *html*?

Here are six different ways (without iterating, as you stated in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74949144/how-to-get-file-path-after-certain-directory-in-java#comment132262470_74949144)). The first two use methods of `java.nio.file.Path`. The next two use methods of `java.lang.String`. The last two use [regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/). Note that there are probably also other ways.

```java
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class PathTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // D:\data\test\html\css\Core.css
        Path path = Paths.get("D:", "data", "test", "html", "css", "Core.css");
        System.out.println("Path: " + path);
        Path afterHtml = Paths.get("D:", "data", "test", "html").relativize(path);
        System.out.println("After 'html': " + afterHtml);
        System.out.println("subpath(3): " + path.subpath(3, path.getNameCount()));
        String str = path.toString();
        System.out.println("replace: " + str.replace("D:\\data\\test\\html\\", ""));
        System.out.println("substring: " + str.substring(str.indexOf("html") + 5));
        System.out.println("split: " + str.split("\\\\html\\\\")[1]);
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\\\html\\\\(.*$)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("regex: " + matcher.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```

Running the above code produces the following output:

```
Path: D:\data\test\html\css\Core.css
After 'html': css\Core.css
subpath(3): css\Core.css
replace: css\Core.css
substring: css\Core.css
split: css\Core.css
regex: css\Core.css
```

I assume you know how to modify the above in order to

> I want to get file path after `/test`